# Biblatex: have "and" in the citation but "&" in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm starting using BibLatex/biber to process my bibliographic entries in Latex. Using the authoryear style as a start, I tweak in order to comply to editorial style of the journal I'll submit my paper to.
One of the tweaks is to replace the default "and" by an ampersand (&) before the last author in the bibliography, using the following code:

```
% Add a comma and replace "and" with "&" before last coauthor
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
   \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
   \addcomma\addspace\&\space}
```

Unfortunately this code does also replace the "and" in citations, contrary to what the journal wants for citations.

My question is, how to replace "and" by "&" only in the bibliography? It seems like biblatex-dw has this option but my document doesn't compile with this style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure `BibLaTeX` has facilities for better and more efficient solutions, a quick hack is the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\newtoggle{incitation}
\pretocmd{\citesetup}{\toggletrue{incitation}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\bibsetup}{\togglefalse{incitation}}{}{}
\newcommand{\biband}{\iftoggle{incitation}{and}{\&}}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
   \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
   \addcomma\addspace\biband\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
 author = "Family, Given and FamilyTwo, GivenTwo",
 title = "title",
 journal = "Journal",
 year = "2012"}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

---

*EDIT*

Based on the suggestion by @Audrey

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\newcommand{\biband}{\ifcurrentname{labelname}{\bibstring{and}}{\&}}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
   \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
   \addcomma\addspace\biband\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
 author = "Family, Given and FamilyTwo, GivenTwo",
 title = "title",
 journal = "Journal",
 year = "2012"}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Sebastien You are welcome. Since the answer solves your problem you might consider accepting the answer (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/16895)

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}% delete backend= when running bibtex

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
 author = "Family, Given and FamilyTwo, GivenTwo and Family3, Given3",
 title = "title",
 journal = "Journal",
 year = "2012"}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
foo\cite{test}

\begingroup
\renewcommand*\finalnamedelim{ \& }
\printbibliography
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 You could use `\AtBeginBibliography` instead. `bibtex` is no longer the default backend.

Comment: TL2012 has biblatex 1.7 and that version has bibtex as main backend and using `AtBeginBibliography` makes no difference here

Comment: @Herbert `biblatex 2.x` has `biber` as `backend`. Thus I would suggest to explicitly set the `backend` in both cases to cater for `biblatex` 1.7 and 2.x

Comment: @Guido, I know, but I am using current version of TeXLive! And setting the backend doesn't hurt.

Comment: @Herbert it is about the comment in the source "delete backed= when running bibtex"