# Use ampersand & in citations and bibliography in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

With `biblatex` and `biber`, citations in the text and the entries in the bibliography use the word `and` before the last author by default. I would like to replace this with the ampersand `&`. My question is very similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67621/biblatex-have-and-in-the-citation-but-in-the-bibliography), except I would like to use `&` *both* in citations and in the bibliography. I assume therefore that there might be a simpler solution than what the answers to that question suggest. Presumably some line in the preamble should take care of this?

Comment: It seems that the code snippet in the linked question (!) already provides the answer to your question.

Comment: @lockstep As mentioned, both the question and the answers I linked to are attempting to accomplish something more complicated than what I am. Hence I assume their suggestions are unnecessary complicated for my purpose. I have no difficulties accepting that that assumption is wrong - if it is.

Comment: I read the linked question again, tested the included code snippet, and it seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @lockstep I'm sure that's true. But since the person who wrote that code is attempting something more complicated, I assume the code is unnecessarily complicated as well (I'm no expert, I can't tell). To some this doesn't matter (if it does the job it does the job). To others it matters (the code should be as simple as possible). As said, if the code in the linked question is minimal enough as it is, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The original definition of `\finalnamedelim` may be found in `biblatex.def`:

```
\newcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
```

Replace `\bibstring{and}` with `\&` and you're set:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

(The additional `\addcomma` in the code snippet provided in the linked question is superfluous; the respective punctuation should be handled by redefining `\finalandcomma`.)

Comment: For people reading this in 2021: `finalnamedelim` is now a *contex-sensitive* delimiter, so you should replace `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}` in the answer above with `\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}`. Everything else still applies.