# BibTeX: Apalike using & instead of and

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

**Intro**

I am currently writing a report on my local language. The usage of "and" in my reference list is not preferable and I would like to use "&" instead of "and" such that the reference list and cite will display with "&" not "and".

I tried manually changeing all "and"s to "\&" in my .bib file. However, this did not solve the problem as the authors suddenly showed up wrong. I am not sure why this happened but I know that it was interpreted wrong.

I have following in my master file:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
...
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to change the reference list such that all "and"'s are interpreted as "&" and displayed as such while maintaining "and" in the .bib file?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [Replace 'and' with ampersand in bibliography and parenthetical citations using BibLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150461/replace-and-with-ampersand-in-bibliography-and-parenthetical-citations-using-b) ... though it is hard to search for things like *"replace and"*

Comment: Note changing your `.bib` file won't work. The software needs to see "and" in the `.bib` file to work, and your use of `\&` will mess it up. What gets printed has nothing to do, in this case, with what is in the `.bib` file.

Comment: @PaulStanley - thx. As described I osberved this. However, even with the suggestion from cslstr I am still not possible to make this work. How would you change the interpretation of and?

Comment: @SteewDK I posted an answer, but it was wrong, so I've deleted it. Meanwhile, are you actually using biblatex? It looks like you are using bibtex?

Comment: @SteewDK OK. Updated/corrected the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit confused, because you have tagged it as Biblatex, but your reference to `apalike` suggests you are using BibTeX.

First off, whichever system you are using, **do not try to change the format of references by changing your `.bib` file**. That file just contains data. How it is formatted depends on other files. Each author should always and only be separate from the others by `and` in that file.

**For BibTeX**

If you are using `apalike`, follow the instructions given in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109226/5404, replacing `" and "` with `" \& "` in two places in the file. Be sure to rename the `.bst` file.

**For BibLaTeX**

The `biblatex-apa` style already uses ampersands (not "and") so there shouldn't be any change to make. If you do ever need to change the "&" or "and" in biblatex, follow the instructions given at [Replace 'and' with ampersand in bibliography and parenthetical citations using BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150461/replace-and-with-ampersand-in-bibliography-and-parenthetical-citations-using-b).

The essential trick is to redefine the `\finalnamedelim` macro. A generally suitable definition is along these lines

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\&\space}%
```

The second line of that deals with the insertion of a comma before the final delimiter, a feature itself controlled by `\finalandcomma`: if you don't want a comma, you can define that macro to produce nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Using LaTex 3.61: Here is how to change "and" for an ampersand "&" in both citations and references using apalike bibliography style.

The solution is to replace `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` for `\biliographystyle{apalike2}`

Comment: This is not an answer, rather new question. To make an attention and answer on it, pleas ask it as question.

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!  If this is a new question, go ahead and ask it by using the "Ask Question" link.  You should first use the search box to check to see if it is already answered.