# Multiple Authors in bibliography separated only by comma

Tags: biblatex

I have the following problem.
I would like to have the authors of the book like in the picture. Last name, first name, last name, first name, last name, first name.
[image]
With Overleaf however I only manage to get this output:
[image]

My code is following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}
\begin{document}
This is an example text \footcite[Vgl.][S.33]{bilanz}
\printbibliography
\begin{filecontents}{myreferences.bib}
@book{bilanz,
address = {D{\"u}sseldorf},
author = {Baetge, J{\"o}rg and Kirsch, Hans-J{\"u}rgen and Thiele, Stefan},
edition = {15},
publisher = {IDW},
title = {Bilanzen},
year = {2019}}
\end{filecontents}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help and have a very pleasant weekend.

Comment: I believe you want to add `giveninits=true` as in `\usepackage[style=authortitle,giveninits=true]{biblatex}`

Comment: If you want to replace the word "und" by the ampersand symbol, this answer appears to show how to do it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150491/140456

Comment: Sadly not. The first one results in Last name, first name, last name first name "und" last name first name. I need it to be like the first screenshot I provided.

Comment: Did you see the answer I linked in the second comment? It replaces the word "und" by "&". Additionally, the edition should appear between parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, the ampersand appears, but the rest does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up the comments here is something I believe serves as an answer:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,giveninits=true,sorting=nyt,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\&\space}%
}

\let\origparencite\parencite
\renewrobustcmd{\parencite}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\&\space}%
  }%
  \origparencite%
}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\begin{filecontents}{myreferences.bib}
@book{bilanz,
address = {D{\"u}sseldorf},
author = {Baetge, J{\"o}rg and Kirsch, Hans-J{\"u}rgen and Thiele, Stefan},
edition = {(15 Ausg.)},
publisher = {IDW},
title = {Bilanzen},
year = {2019}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

\begin{document}
This is an example text \footcite[Vgl.][S.33]{bilanz}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was great.

Comment: It is nice that this is useful

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few simplifications of the code in the question and in [Luis Turcio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/140456/luis-turcio)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/589144/35864)

1. The `\AtBeginBibliography` and `\renewrobustcmd` are no longer needed to redefine `finalnamedelim` 'locally'. Use `\DeclareDelimFormat` and its optional argument instead. (See also my answer to the linked [Replace 'and' with ampersand in bibliography and parenthetical citations using BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150461/35864.))
2. If you want *Neue Rechtschreibung* you need `ngerman` not `german` as `babel` option.
3. `sorting=nyt,` is the default with `style=authoryear,` so can be dropped.
4. In general it is recommended to add as little markup to the `.bib` file as possible. The parentheses around the edition can be obtained via field formats and should not be hard-coded in the `.bib` file.
5. `biblatex` can automatically add the prefix "p."/"pp." ("S.") for pages in the postnote. So you don't need `\footcite[Vgl.][S.33]{bilanz}`, it is enough to say `\footcite[Vgl.][33]{bilanz}`.
6. Since you use Biber, you can use non-ASCII chars like `ü` and `ö` directly in the `.bib` file. There is no need to escape them to `{\"u}` and `{\"o}`. (If you are using pdfLaTeX [and not LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX], you will want to load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to allow TeX to hyphenate words containing non-ASCII chars. If you have a very old version of LaTeX [older than April 2018], you will also need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Both of these concerns do not apply when you use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, which support UTF8 out of the box. In any case, make sure your document is encoded in UTF8.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
 
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,parencite]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}%

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \mkbibparens{%
    \ifinteger{#1}
      {\mkbibordedition{#1}~\bibstring{edition}}
      {#1\isdot}}\nopunct}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bilanz,
  author    = {Baetge, Jörg and Kirsch, Hans-Jürgen and Thiele, Stefan},
  title     = {Bilanzen},
  edition   = {15},
  publisher = {IDW},
  year      = {2019},
  address   = {Düsseldorf},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is an example text \footcite[Vgl.][33]{bilanz}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Baetge, J., Kirsch, H.-J. & Thiele, S. (2019). Bilanzen. (15. Aufl.) Düsseldorf: IDW.]

[image: Footnote 1: Vgl. Baetge, Kirsch und Thiele 2019, S. 33.]