# Footcite all Authors

Tags: biblatex

I need the footcite to display all authors like this.
However I only got so far that it shows only the last name of the first author. In this case "Horschitz".
[image: Footcite of all Authors]
Here my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,giveninits=true,sorting=nyt,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\&\space}%
}

\let\origparencite\parencite
\renewrobustcmd{\parencite}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\&\space}%
  }%
  \origparencite%
}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\begin{filecontents}{myreferences.bib}
@book{bilstr,
    address = {Stuttgart},
    author = {Horschitz, Harald and Gro{\ss}, Walter and Fanck, Bernfried and Guschl, Harald and Kirschbaum, J{\"u}rgen and Schustek, Heribert},
    date-added = {2021-03-27 23:38:45 +0100},
    shorttitle ={Bilanzsteuerrecht},
    date-modified = {2021-03-27 23:41:36 +0100},
    edition = {14},
    publisher = {},
    series = {Finanz und Steuern},
    title = {Bilanzsteuerrecht und Buchf{\"u}hrung},
    volume = {1},
    year = {2016}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

\begin{document}
This is an example text \footcite[Vgl.][S.33]{bilstr}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `maxnames` to a high value like `999` to display all name. Set the `labelname` format to `sortname` to display the given name initial as well.

I also added some code to add slashes between names in the citation. I explicitly only changed this for `\footcite` and not for the bibliography and `\parencite`, because your MWE has different code for those. (I slightly modernised that code, but left the function intact.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  sorting=nyt,
  maxnames=999,
  giveninits=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,parencite]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat[footcite]{multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\DeclareDelimAlias[footcite]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{sortname}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bilstr,
  address    = {Stuttgart},
  author     = {Horschitz, Harald and Groß, Walter and Fanck, Bernfried
                and Guschl, Harald and Kirschbaum, Jürgen and Schustek, Heribert},
  shorttitle = {Bilanzsteuerrecht},
  edition    = {14},
  series     = {Finanz und Steuern},
  title      = {Bilanzsteuerrecht und Buchführung},
  volume     = {1},
  year       = {2016},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is an example text \footcite[Vgl.][33]{bilstr}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Vgl. Horschitz, H./Groß, W./Fanck, B./Guschl, H./Kirschbaum, J./Schustek, H. 2016, S. 33.]

If you prefer a more consistent output, replace

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,parencite]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat[footcite]{multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\DeclareDelimAlias[footcite]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
```

with

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
```

I'd also like to point you to [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591238/35864) to [one of your earlier questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/589130/35864). In particular I recommend you drop the "S." in the `postnote` and let `biblatex` add it for you. You can also use `ü` and `ß` directly instead of `{\"u}` and `{\ss}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped :-)
The thing is about the {\"u} and {\ss} that I use Bibdesk and it adds them automatically. But you're right about "S". I already changed that.