# Changing "and" to & in chem-acs style biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I wrote my thesis in a latex template, and it had the `chem-acs` style by default in the references. It is in spanish, and the problem is that it puts "y" when it shows the last author and shows all the authors of the article, and when I remove the last of them and put "and others", it puts "y col" (which means and colaborators, in spanish). I want to keep the same style of references (`chem-acs`), but instead of what I mentioned, I need it to show only the first three authors, and if there are more, to put `et al`, not `y col`. Also, I need to have an ampersand (`&`) instead of `y` before the last author. I already tried [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109221/change-citation-conjunction-from-and-to-i) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68053/use-ampersand-in-citations-and-bibliography-in-biblatex), but nothing works. This is the part of template regarding the references (in the .cls).

```
\usepackage[style = chem-acs, backend=biber, urldate=long,
            dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References/references.bib}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
```

This is what I have in references.tex

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect \textbf{Referencias}}
\nocite{*}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Referencias}           
\printbibliography
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me

Answer (score 4):

The number of names shown can be controlled with `minnames` and `maxnames`. (Name lists exceeding `maxnames` are shortened to `minnames`+"et al.".)

The "&" between the last and second-to-last author can be obtained by redefining `finalnamedelim`, but if you are writing in a language with `smartand` feature (such as `spanshs`), you also need to reset an internal macro for that to work properly.

You get the "et al." by redefining the `andothers` bibstring.

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=chem-acs,
  minnames=3, maxnames=3,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{%
  \restorecommand\lbx@finalnamedelim
}
\makeatother

\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,aksin,nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (1) Sigfridsson, E. & Ryde, U. Journal of Computational Chemistry 1998, 19, 377-395.//(2) Aksın, Ö.; Türkmen, H.; Artok, L. et al. J. Organomet. Chem. 2006, 691, 3027-3036.]

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly

Comment: @SilviaRueda Glad I could help. If the answer helped you, you may want to consider upvoting and/or accepting it, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.