# biblatex: test whether a command is inside a cite command

Tags: biblatex, citing, conditionals

The idea is the following: Normally, `\fullcite` just prints the full bibliography entry by calling `\usedriver`. In my style `biblatex-fiwi` I added the option to suppress stuff like `foreword` and  `afterword`. At the moment, this option is for both, the bibliographic entry and the result of `\fullcite`.

I'd like to have the possibility to distinguish between the result of `\printbibliography` and `\fullcite`. But since `\fullcite` relies on the same mechanism as `\printbibliography`, this is tricky. What I need is a test which tells me whether we are currently inside a `\cite` command. This would then allow me to add a `\fullcite`-only option.

As far as I know, no test of this kind exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything wrong with `\ifbibliography` (see section 4.6.2 of the manual for details)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{\ifbibliography{}{\clearname{foreword}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  foreword = {Buthor, B.},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{A01}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: D'oh, not only is there `\ifbibliography`, there is also `\ifcitation`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I don't *think* there's a built-in way to do this [*update: wrong*]: at least, if there is, I don't know it [*that part, sadly, was not: see Lockstep's answer for the correct approach*].

The easiest way, I think, would be to do something with `\AtBeginBibliography`. Options include: setting some sort of toggle which you can test in your driver, and which would indicate that it was being called within a bibliography environment [*that's unnecessary, because one is already provided*], or setting up a driver alias to trigger at that point, so that you effectively replace the driver that `\fullcite` will "see" with another driver that only takes effect in the bibliography [*I think that remains a possible alternative, which could be sensible if there was a lot that needed changing*].

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67621/16895

Comment: @Guido The test used there ensures `\fullcite` generates the same output as the bibliography. For the problem here `\ifbibliography` or `\ifcitation` work just fine.