# How to change string 'and' in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

When the reference has 2 authors I would like the citation to appear as:

```
Sutherland & Varnam
```

Also, when the bibliography is printed (at the end of the manuscript) I don't want to see any `and` or `&` before the last author - just a list with all authors.

Comment: The first question is, I guess, a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68053/use-ampersand-in-citations-and-bibliography-in-biblatex? See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67621/biblatex-have-and-in-the-citation-but-in-the-bibliography

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Combining this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68057/27635) of lockstep and this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150491/27635) of mine, you can add the following lines to change `and` to `&` globally

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}
```

and the following lines to change `and` to `,` in the bibliography

```
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\addcomma\space}%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Sutherland and Varnam},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\addcomma\space}%
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Here we cite \cite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]